# Folders in the sidebar component (react.js dashboard) doesn't always open when I click them

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-component

#### Story

I'm using this `react.js` template http://skote-v-light.react.themesbrand.com/email-read from https://themeforest.net/item/skote-react-admin-dashboard-template/26318700 for building my react app.

I use and modify the sidebar component from the template and name it `Sidebar.js`.

There is `SidebarContent.js` for building the content inside the sidebar.

There is `MenuComponent.js` inside `SidebarContent.js` for building the menu inside the sidebar.

`MenuComponent.js` takes a list from `menuList.js` and renders it.

There are two dummy pages which are Route/Summary page (`Summary.js`) and Payload page (`Payload.js`) inside the Sidebar. I combine them all inside `PageWithSidebar.js`.

#### Question

Why don't always the `ABC, DEF, etc` folders in the sidebar open when I click them?

#### Ideal Condition I Wanted

Every folder (`ABC, DEF, etc`) inside the sidebar always opens when I click one of them.

#### Actual Condition

**Please watch this demo to understand the context:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lig1SKKRtyRqxWm_OYNkuQennrytV0jo/view?usp=sharing

Steps:

1. Click the `Route/Summary` option inside the `ABC` folder -> `Summary` page is shown (as I wanted)
2. Click the `Payload` option inside the `ABC` folder -> `Payload` page is shown (as I wanted)
3. Click another `Route/Summary` option inside the `ABC` folder -> `Summary` page is shown (as I wanted)
4. Close the `ABC` folder -> The folder closes (as I wanted)
5. Click the `DEF` folder -> **The folder doesn't open (not I wanted)**

There is no error or warning log in the browser console.

#### Code

**PageWithSidebar.js:**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

// COMPONENTS
import Sidebar from '../../components/Menu/Sidebar/Sidebar'

// PAGES
// ROUTE
import Summary from '../Routes/Summary/Summary'
// PAYLOAD
import Payload from '../Payload/Payload'

const PageWithSidebar = () => {
    return(
        <div id="layout-wrapper">
            <Sidebar/>
            <div className="main-content">
                <Switch>
                    {/* ROUTE */}
                    <Route path="/route/summary/location=:locationName">
                        <Summary/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/payload/location=:locationName">
                        <Payload/>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PageWithSidebar
```

**Sidebar.js:**

```js
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

// COMPONENTS
import SidebarContent from './SidebarContent'

// IMAGES
import IconClose from '../../../images/icons/close.svg'
import IconOpen from '../../../images/icons/open.svg'

const Sidebar = () => {

    const toogleSidebar = () => {
        var body = document.body;
        body.classList.toggle("vertical-collpsed");
        body.classList.toggle("sidebar-enable");
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="vertical-menu">
                <div className="navbar-brand-box">
                    <Link to='/' className="logo logo-dark">
                        {/* SIDEBAR IS CLOSED */}
                        <span className="logo-sm">
                            {/* TOOGLE SIDEBAR BUTTON */}
                            <img src={IconOpen} alt='' className='icon-open' onClick={toogleSidebar}/>
                        </span>

                        {/* SIDEBAR IS OPEN */}
                        <span className="logo-lg sidebar-is-open-container">
                            {/* TOOGLE SIDEBAR BUTTON */}
                            <img src={IconClose} alt='' className='icon-close' onClick={toogleSidebar}/>
                        </span>
                    </Link>
                </div>

                {/* SIDEBAR CONTENT */}
                <SidebarContent />

                <div className="sidebar-background"></div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default Sidebar
```

**SidebarContent.js:**

```js
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
import { withRouter, Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom"

// Import Scrollbar
import SimpleBar from "simplebar-react"

// MetisMenu
import MetisMenu from "metismenujs"

//i18n
import { withTranslation } from "react-i18next"

// COMPONENTS
import MenuComponent from './MenuComponent'

// IMAGES
import IconFolderGray from '../../../images/icons/folder-gray.svg'
import IconFolderRed from '../../../images/icons/folder-red.svg'
import IconLogout from '../../../images/icons/logout.svg'

// MENU ITEMS
import menuList from './menuList/menuList'

// STYLES
import './styles.scss'
import logoutUser from '../../../utils/authentication/logOut'

const SidebarContent = props => {

    // MY OWN CODE SECTION
    const location = useLocation()
    const pathName = location['pathname']
    let locationName = ''
    if(pathName.includes('route')) {
        locationName = pathName.split('/')[3].replace('location=', '')
    }
    else {
        locationName = pathName.split('/')[2].replace('location=', '')
    }
    // console.log('SidebarContent, locationName:', locationName)
    
    // TEMPLATE CODE SECTION
    const ref = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        const pathName = props.location.pathname

        const initMenu = () => {
            new MetisMenu("#side-menu")
            let matchingMenuItem = null
            const ul = document.getElementById("side-menu")
            const items = ul.getElementsByTagName("a")

            for (let i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
                if (pathName === items[i].pathname) {
                    matchingMenuItem = items[i]
                    break
                }
            }

            if (matchingMenuItem) {
                activateParentDropdown(matchingMenuItem)
            }
        }
        
        initMenu()
    }, [props.location.pathname])

    useEffect(() => {
        ref.current.recalculate()
    })

    function scrollElement(item) {
        if (item) {
            const currentPosition = item.offsetTop
            if (currentPosition > window.innerHeight) {
                ref.current.getScrollElement().scrollTop = currentPosition - 300
            }
        }
    }

    function activateParentDropdown(item) {
        item.classList.add("active")
        const parent = item.parentElement
        const parent2El = parent.childNodes[1]
        if (parent2El && parent2El.id !== "side-menu") {
            parent2El.classList.add("mm-show")
        }

        if (parent) {
            parent.classList.add("mm-active")
            const parent2 = parent.parentElement

            if (parent2) {
                parent2.classList.add("mm-show") // ul tag

                const parent3 = parent2.parentElement // li tag

                if (parent3) {
                    parent3.classList.add("mm-active") // li
                    parent3.childNodes[0].classList.add("mm-active") //a
                    const parent4 = parent3.parentElement // ul
                    if (parent4) {
                        parent4.classList.add("mm-show") // ul
                        const parent5 = parent4.parentElement
                        if (parent5) {
                            parent5.classList.add("mm-show") // li
                            parent5.childNodes[0].classList.add("mm-active") // a tag
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            scrollElement(item);
            return false
        }
        scrollElement(item);
        return false
    }

    // MY OWN CODE SECTION
    const itemList = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO', 'PQR']

    const [ selectedItem, setSelectedItem ] = useState(itemList.indexOf(locationName.toUpperCase()))

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <SimpleBar style={{ maxHeight: "100%" }} ref={ref}>
                <div id="sidebar-menu">
                    <ul className="metismenu list-unstyled sidebar-content-menu-container" id="side-menu">
                        {/* TITLE */}
                        <li className="menu-title sidebar-content-site-profile-title">Dummy Locations</li>

                        {/* ITEMS */}
                        {
                            itemList.map((item, index) => (
                                <li
                                    key={index}
                                    className={selectedItem === index ? 'sidebar-content-dropdown-selected' : 'sidebar-content-dropdown'}
                                    // onClick={() => setSelectedItem(index)}
                                >
                                    {/* TITLE */}
                                    <Link to="/" className="has-arrow dropdown-link">
                                        {/* FOLDER ICON */}
                                        <img 
                                            src={selectedItem === index ? IconFolderRed : IconFolderGray} 
                                            alt='' 
                                            className='bx sidebar-content-icon-folder-gray'
                                        />
                                        
                                        {/* TEXT */}
                                        <span className='dropdown-span'>
                                            {item}
                                        </span>
                                    </Link>

                                    {/* MENU COMPONENT*/}
                                    <ul className="sub-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                                        <div className='border-line'></div>
                                        <MenuComponent list={menuList} pathName={item.toLowerCase()}/>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            ))
                        }

                        {/* PROFILE */}
                        <li className='sidebar-content-single-item-container'>
                            <Link to='/'>
                                <div onClick={logoutUser}>
                                    <img src={IconLogout} alt='' className='sidebar-content-icon-single-item'/>
                                    <span className='sidebar-content-span-single-item'>Logout</span>
                                </div>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </SimpleBar>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

SidebarContent.propTypes = {
    location: PropTypes.object,
    t: PropTypes.any,
}

export default withRouter(withTranslation()(SidebarContent))
```

**MenuComponent.js:**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

const MenuComponent = (props) => {
    const [ selectedItem, setSelectedItem ] = useState(0)

    return(
        props['list'].map((item, index) => (
            <li 
                key={index}
                onClick={() => setSelectedItem(index)}
            >
                <Link 
                    to={`${item['path']}/location=${props['pathName']}`}
                    className='menu-component-root'
                >
                    {/* CIRCLE */}
                    <div className={selectedItem === index ? 'circle-selected' : 'circle'}></div>

                    {/* TEXT */}
                    <p className='text'>
                        {item['text']}
                    </p>
                </Link>
            </li>
        ))
    )
}

export default MenuComponent
```

**menuList.js:**

```js
const menuList = [
    {
        path: '/route/summary',
        text: 'Route/Summary'
    },
    {
        path: '/route/summary',
        text: 'Route/Summary'
    },
    {
        path: '/payload',
        text: 'Payload'
    },
    {
        path: '/route/summary',
        text: 'Route/Summary'
    },
    {
        path: '/route/summary',
        text: 'Route/Summary'
    },
    {
        path: '/route/summary',
        text: 'Route/Summary'
    },
    {
        path: '/route/summary',
        text: 'Route/Summary'
    }
]

export default menuList
```

**Summary.js:**

```js
import React from "react"

import { Row, Col } from "reactstrap"

// STYLES
import './styles.scss'

const Summary = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="container-fluid route-summary-root">
                <Row>
                    <Col className="col-12">
                        {/* TOP CONTAINER */}
                        <div className='top-container'>

                            {/* LEFT CONTAINER */}
                            <div className='top-left-container'>
                                <h3 className='title'> Route/Summary Page</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default Summary
```

**Payload.js:**

```js
import React from "react"

import { Row, Col } from "reactstrap"

// STYLES
import './styles.scss'

const Payload = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="container-fluid payload-root">
                <Row>
                    <Col className="col-12">
                        {/* TOP CONTAINER */}
                        <div className='top-container'>

                            {/* LEFT CONTAINER */}
                            <div className='top-left-container'>
                                <h3 className='title'>Payload Page</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default Payload
```

**Note: let me know if the question is confusing. I will try to update it.**